# How to work with multiple classes using BeautifulSoup & BS4

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, youtube

I am trying to write youtube scraper and as part of my task I need to work with multiple classes at bs4.

HTML looks like

```html
<span id="video-title" class="style-scope ytd-playlist-panel-video-renderer">
</span>
```

My aim to use class attribute to get all 50 different music and work with them.
I have tried like that and it returns me nothing.

```py
soup_obj.find_all("span", {"class":"style-scope ytd-playlist-panel-video-renderer"})
```

and I also tried as Selenium style (instead of spaces between class pass dot(.)

```py
soup_obj.find_all("span", {"class":"style-scope.ytd-playlist-panel-video-renderer"})
```

Does anyone have idea about it ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```py
soup_obj.find_all("span", {"class":["style-scope", "ytd-playlist-panel-video-renderer"]})
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: Are you sure the locator is correct? Can you share the link to that youtube and describe what are you trying to do there?

Comment: Yes I do, we can test with any youtube playlist. Let's look at this one. soup_obj.find_all("a", {"class":["yt-simple-endpoint", "style-scope" , "ytd-playlist-panel-video-renderer"]})  for this link : https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4fGSI1pDJn4fmCoF1vKHLtivI0f9yHiF

Comment: OK, but you still didn't explain what exactly are you trying to do there?

Comment: Yes I did and I told you it returned me 0 items. Which mean code is not able to fetch data from html. I have tried with Selenium and it works but with bs4 it didnt worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you can't send multiple classnames within:

```
driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "classname")
```

---

If your aim is to use only ***class*** attribute then you need to pass only a single *`classname`* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *classname* as `style-scope`:

  ```
  elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "style-scope")
  ```
- Using *classname* as `style-scope`:

  ```
  elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "ytd-playlist-panel-video-renderer")
  ```

---

To pass both the *classnames* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.style-scope.ytd-playlist-panel-video-renderer")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='style-scope ytd-playlist-panel-video-renderer']")
  ```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help for detailed answer. The problem is I am trying to find it out via bs4 not with selenium. Because in Selenium you can do with multiple spaces. It is fine. Just dot between spaces work it out in all my projects but for bs4 dunno what to do